# Random value instance shared between classes

Tags: java, random, integer

I have a method that returns a random value.

```
  public int newRandom() {
      Random random = new Random();
      int o = random.nextInt(9 - 0 + 1) + 0;
      return o;
}
```

After I generate that value I'm currently setting a variable inside another method to the result of this function, what I want to do is have another class know the same result that variable has, what I mean is both having the same random number, I for some reason can't figure this out on my own. What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: What is the application you will use the random numbers in?  Does your application care about reproducible "randomness"?  Can you try making your class hold its own `Random` instance, or store "random" numbers it recently generated, rather than creating a new `Random` instance every time `newRandom()` is called?

Comment: @PeterO.My ideal scenario is the following, inside a method to be executed I set into a variable the value of newRandom();, than I proceed to use that stored random number in the function, what I want would be to have the instance of that variable that has the random number, inside another class instance.

Comment: Your response is difficult to follow.  I ask again:  What  is the application you will use the random numbers in?  (A game, a simulation, something else?)  Also, please edit your question to clarify.  Also, if you want two "classes" to have the same "random numbers", the usual way to do so is to have both classes use the same seed (e.g., use `new Random(seed)` rather than `new Random()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class A
{

    public static Random random = new Random();

}


public class B
{

    public int getRandomInt()
    {
        return A.random.nextInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok but I need the "getRandomInt()" in A and B to give me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Base class with a public static variable and when you inherit these new classes from the Base class and create new instances they share this same variable:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Base_class {
  public static int o;

  public Base_class() {
  }

  public int newRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();
        o = random.nextInt(9 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        return o;
  }

  public int get_randn() {
    return o;
  }
}

class Derived_class1 extends Base_class {
  public Derived_class1() {
  }
}

class Derived_class2 extends Base_class {
  public Derived_class2() {
  }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Derived_class1 obj1 = new Derived_class1();
    Derived_class2 obj2 = new Derived_class2();
    obj1.newRandom();
    System.out.println(obj1.get_randn());
    System.out.println(obj2.get_randn());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using composition where multiple objects (could be different classes) share the same instance of a class which provides the random values.  For example, given this class to keep track of random values:

```
    private class RandomProvider {
        private final Random random = new Random();
        private int currentValue;

        private int newRandom() {
            currentValue = random.nextInt(10);
            return currentValue;
        }

        private int getCurrentValue() {
            return currentValue;
        }
    }
```

and another class (or classes) which use a `RandomProvider`:

```
    private class A {
        private final RandomProvider randomProvider;

        private A(RandomProvider randomProvider) {
            this.randomProvider = randomProvider;
        }

        private int getCurrentRandomValue() {
            return randomProvider.getCurrentValue();
        }
    }
```

So then a couple instances of `A` (or some other class) can use the **same** instance of `RandomProvider`:

```
    RandomProvider randomProvider = new RandomProvider();
    System.out.println("new random value is " + randomProvider.newRandom());

    A a1 = new A(randomProvider);
    System.out.println("A1 sees current random value as " + a1.getCurrentRandomValue());

    A a2 = new A(randomProvider);
    System.out.println("A2 sees current random value as " + a2.getCurrentRandomValue());

    randomProvider.newRandom();
    System.out.println("A1 sees current random value as " + a1.getCurrentRandomValue());
    System.out.println("A2 sees current random value as " + a2.getCurrentRandomValue());
```

Sample output:

```
new random value is 9
A1 sees current random value as 9
A2 sees current random value as 9
A1 sees current random value as 3
A2 sees current random value as 3
```

Comment: Ok but how would I make the other class have the same random number as a1 for example?

Comment: An instance of class A and an instance of class B would both use the same instance of `RandomProvider`.